# Mails not sending in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created a store in magento.Order confirmation mails are not sending to customers or admin.

What i am missing please advice

Comment: check system > configuration > sales > sales emails > enabled : yes

Comment: did you install magento in your local server ?

Comment: Emails are sent via cron. You need to have this setup as well.

Answer (score 3):

To send the Order confirmation email, you will have setup cron in Magento. From version 1.9 Magento sends all the order email in a queue via Cron.

To enable the cron you will have to call either cron.php or cron.sh. There are several ways to set the cronjob in Magento

1) Via cPanel: This is the easiest way. You can check this article to setup [cron via cPanel](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/cron_jobs.htm)

You need to run below command:

```
curl -s -o /dev/null http://www.yourwebsite.com/cron.php
```

2) Via Shell: You can check this [article](http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Setting_up_the_Magento_cronjob) for it

For confirmation of cron being run properly you can use this extension [AOE SCHEDULER](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html)

Hope it helps